# UICollectionViewCell Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am developing an iOS application in Swift.

I have create a UICollectionViewController. I have filled the UICollectionViewCells with images. How can I connect the cells individual with the different ViewController  for example if i tap the first cell they will show the next ViewController (but the new ViewController need no data from the cell the content is completely different. I will only that they open the next view controller and this for every image in the UiCollectionView.

With prepareforsegue I have the problem that when I tap on every image that the same ViewController is showing. I want that every image open a different new ViewController. Which function does I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues define the viewController they are transitioning to.  If each cell needs to go to a different viewController, then you need a segue for each one.

1. Wire your segues from the viewController icon at the top of your `UICollectionViewController` and not from the prototype cell:

   [image: wiring the segue]
2. Give each of these segues a unique identifier in the *Attributes Inspector*:

   [image: set segue ID]
3. In `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`, select the correct segue identifier using `indexPath` and call `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)`:

   ```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       let segues = ["goToVC1", "goToVC2", "goToVC3"]
       let segueID = segues[indexPath.item]
       performSegueWithIdentifier(segueID, sender: self)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks very helpful